# .then not waiting for resolve from Promise

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, mern, google-identity-toolkit

I am using Google Identity Services to setup login for my webpage. I am doing API calls in a async function which returns a Promise resolve but the .then function is executed even before the Promise is resolved. I am temporarily managing it with setTimeout but it isnt a good approach right so please help me out in finding the

```
const connectOAuth = async () => {
    /* global google */
    await google.accounts.id.initialize({
      client_id: "133396583135-1rar9q7nq2fotg5h6qk085i97s37hi5u.apps.googleusercontent.com",
      callback: handleCallBackResponse
    })
    await google.accounts.id.renderButton(document.getElementById("loginButton"), {theme: "outline", size: "large"})
    await google.accounts.id.prompt()
    return Promise.resolve()
  }
  
  useEffect(() => {
    connectOAuth().then(setTimeout(() => {setLoading(false)}, 1000))
  }, [])
```

error

The loading screen should turn off once API calls are done but it goes off before hand spoiling entire css of my webpage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The posted code is calling `setTimeout` when evaluating the argument passed to `then`:

```
connectOAuth().then(setTimeout(() => {setLoading(false)}, 1000))
```

executes

```
setTimeout(() => {setLoading(false)}, 1000)
```

(which starts the timeout) before calling `then`.

Now because `async` functions return a pending promise when they process an `await` keyword, the `then` method is called on the promise returned when

```
google.accounts.id.initialize
```

is called, but before `initialize` has performed any asynchronous work.
The solution is to register a promise listener, using `then`, without calling the listener in the process. E.G.

```
connectOAuth().then(
  ()=> setTimeout(() => {setLoading(false)}, 1000)
);
```

---

Note that returning `promise.resolve()` from an async function is superfluous - falling out the bottom of an `async` function returns `undefined` which will be used to fulfill the promise returned from calling the async function.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your `.then()` part of the promise chain. The syntax is wrong. The correct syntax for handling promises is:

```js
somePendingPromise.then(resp => { /* handle the response */ })
```

So to fix your code, you need to adjust your code like below:

```js
connectOAuth().then(resp => { 
   console.log(resp);
   setTimeout(() => {setLoading(false)}, 1000);
})
```

But if you wish to write a better code, I would recommend you use states for handling all your responses.

###### Solution for handling responses using states

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

    <!-- Don't use this in production: -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">
    
      function MyApp() {
        const [text, setText] = React.useState('');
        const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(false);
      
        const connectOAuth = async () => {
           setIsLoading(true);
           // some delayed task here
           const resp = await fetch("https://hub.dummyapis.com/delay?seconds=2");
           const text = await resp.text();
           
           // then handle the response
           setText(text);
           setIsLoading(false);
        }

        React.useEffect(() => {
          connectOAuth();
        }, [])
      
        return (
          <>
            {isLoading ? <span>Loading...</span> : ''} 
            {text && <span>{text}</span>} 
          </>
        )
        
      }

      const container = document.getElementById('root');
      const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(container);
      root.render(<MyApp />);

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```